# Import an Maven dependency (Example Jsoup.jar)

Tags: maven, grails, jsoup, grails-2.3

I have a generally understanding Problem with the Maven-Dependency in `Grails 2.3.8`.
I want to Import `jsoup` - functionality into my Project.

Therefore I did this in my `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
 dependencies {
.
.
        /// jsoup
        compile  "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3"            
}
```

All is okay. Grails downloads the jar File into my local repo

> C:\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.7.3

Now my confusion. I thougt all is done and i can write my code against Jsoup but this is wrong. I have to

- copy the jar file into the Grails - lib Folder
- set up the buildpath for Jsoup.jar
- do a "grails compile"

Is this the right way? 
Why do i config dependencies when grails doesnt use them? 
 It seems there is  a plugin (compile ":html-cleaner:0.2") where Jsoup is included but when i need Jsoup i use Jsoup and not html-cleaner.

When i did this without my steps i got an Compiler Error:

```
package f

import grails.transaction.Transactional
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
/***
 * 
 * @author MG
 *
 */
//@Transactional
class xyService {

    def getXyFromIndex(String searchKeyword) {
        def html  = ""
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);       

    }
}
```

==> 'Groovy:unable to resolve class org.jsoup.nodes.Document' -GGTS 3.5.1

Comment: Adding the dependency to the `BuildConfig.groovy` is the way to do it. Please provide the code where you use jsoup and please provide your compilation errors.

Comment: The Result is compiler-error (GGTS 3.5.1)
'Groovy:unable to resolve class org.jsoup.nodes.Document'

Comment: Please add it to the question. Not as a comment

Comment: What happens if you run `grails clean-all`, `grails refresh-dependencies` and then `grails compile` on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy jar it should automatically get copied either by ivy or maven. Maven is recommended so in  BuildConfig.groovy  change the resolver value to maven like below. Now when you start your application all jar will get copied to .m2 directory.

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
```

Comment: This is the default value in my BuildConfig.groovy-File

`grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"`

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to import JSoup at the top of your file ?

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element
import org.jsoup.select.Elements
import org.jsoup.parser.Tag

@Transactional
class myClass {

}
```